# How to clear the Flash cache?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash

I'm making this web application in Visual Studio, and it's being unresponsive to some changes I'm making to .xml files that are referenced outside the directory of the project.

I can remove the file completely, and it'll still operate like the file is there.

So it must be stuck in some cache or something. The flash file is actually doing the request, so I assume that it's that cache that needs clearing, as opposed to the VS2010 cache.

So how I can I clear this? I've gone into the flash settings and deleted the cache as far as I could from there, and I ran CC cleaner on basic settings.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend, example in chrome:

Open an incognito window

Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.

Select New incognito window.

A new window will open with the incognito icon  in the corner. You can continue browsing as normal in the other window.

You can also use the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+N (Windows, Linux, and Chrome OS) and ⌘-Shift-N (Mac) to open an incognito window.

Windows 8 users: To switch between windows, click the window switcher  on the top right corner.

Comment: That's certainly an thinking-outside-the-box solution. It works, but it's a bit of a pain to open a new Incognito window.